# How do i create a key with FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I program a **key** in my FirebaseDatabase that is created by the **userName**. **wText** should then be the **text: ""** Value.

I try to create a key but when i run my app it removes all values in my database

The Code:

`

```
            // getting text from our edittext fields.
            String nameValue = userName.getText().toString();
            String textValue = wText.getText().toString();

            // below line is for checking whether the
            // edittext fields are empty or not.
            if (nameValue.isEmpty() && textValue.isEmpty()) {
                // if the text fields are empty
                // then show the below message.
                Toast.makeText(AddTextActivity.this, "Please add some data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                // else call the method to add
                // data to our database.
                addDatatoFirebase(nameValue, textValue);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

}

    private void addDatatoFirebase(String name, String wText) {
        // below 3 lines of code is used to set
        // data in our object class.
        Messages.setuserName(name);
        Messages.setText(wText);

        // we are use add value event listener method
        // which is called with database reference.
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // inside the method of on Data change we are setting
                // our object class to our database reference.
                // data base reference will sends data to firebase.
                myRef.setValue(text);

                // after adding this data we are showing toast message.
                Toast.makeText(AddTextActivity.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // if the data is not added or it is cancelled then
                // we are displaying a failure toast message.
                Toast.makeText(AddTextActivity.this, "Fail to add data" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }); `
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

**It seems you might be using set()**  **function to update data in firebase.**

*( in your case setValue(), I'm not sure if it is Firebase function or user defined function , Firebase uses set() method in almost in every SDK, not sure about Java SDK for Firebase )*

Please note that set() will **replace the existing value**, or create a new key if there isn't any.

> **Use update() function instead of set()**

> **Ways to Save Data**
>
> **set**   - Write or replace data to a defined path, like messages/users/
>
> **update**    - Update some of the keys for a defined path without replacing all of the data
>
> **push** - Add to a list of data in the database. Every time you push a new node onto a list, your database generates a unique key, like
> messages/users//
>
> **transaction**   - Use transactions when working with complex data that could be corrupted by concurrent updates

refer the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Comment: Thank i found a solution. Can you tell me how to fix problems with my RecyclerView. Whenever I open another activity and create a new database entry, then go back to the activitiy my item.xml fields are always shown twice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, But happy to help with Firebase. Are you saying that key, and value pairs in your firebase are duplicating?

Comment: No when i go to the send page, write the db entry and go back to the MainActivity all recyclerview items are duplicated. Then i close the app and reopen it and all is normel. Non of the RecyclerView Items are duplicated after reopen the app

Comment: I assume you're working on a android app. If that's the case, I'm sorry I can't help you :)